# MobileFirst 7.1 custom two step authentication implementation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am attempting to implement a two-step (technically 3 step) authentication system using MobileFirst 7.1 java adapters and custom authentication java classes.

As stated in the documentation custom authenticators should not do the actual validation of the credentials, it is used to only collect credentials from the client. The authenticator then forwards those credentials to the custom login module to perform the login function.

How do we implement a multi-factor authentication system using these? I have read the two-step auth tutorial extensively but that is for adapter based authentication.

I have come up with a couple of options.

1. Actually perform the authentication in the authenticator class. Once I have validated the password I could return an AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS to let the login module create the user identity.
2. Collect the credentials individually by returning AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS per challenge response and let the login module validate and throw an exception with a predetermined error code to be caught in the authenticator and return an AuthenticationStatus.CLIENT_INTERACTION_REQUIRED

My authentication server has a multi-factor auth flow as follows.

1. Validate User Id > Auth server checks userId and returns challenge question
2. Validate answer > Auth server checks answer and returns valid answer response
3. Validate password > Auth server checks password and returns success response

In my particular use case, I cannot collect username, challenge answer, password all in one go. They must be called sequentially. It's not guaranteed that my auth server will issue a challenge to every user.

The two solutions above seem hacky and not intended MFP design. I am concerned about future updates breaking the implementation.

Comment: well, if you have been following v8.0, the security framework is... different, so something is going to break either way...

Comment: @IdanAdar Hey Idan, yeah I have been following 8.0. It is definitely on the radar but we're going to move into production with 7.1 for the time being. I am leaning toward implementation #1 at the moment. Digging through the source code of the "CustomIdentityProvider" it looks like there is some validation occurring for 3rd party api's in that authenticator. Any thoughts on this?